# JS cookie for displaying content after x-th pageview only once

Tags: jquery, cookies

I found this code here, but I am not able to modify it to open the pop-up only once during the period of validity of the cookies. Can anyone please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// if the cookie is undefined, create it
if(typeof Cookies.get('visited') === "undefined"){
    Cookies.set("visited", 0);
}
// Cookies.get('visited') returns a string
if (parseInt(Cookies.get('visited')) >= 3) {
    // open fancybox after 3 secs on 4th visit
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.fancybox.open({
            // your fancybox API options here
        });
    }, 3000);
} else {
    let increase = parseInt(Cookies.get('visited')) + 1;
    Cookies.set('visited', increase, { expires: 1 });
    return false;
}
}); // ready
```

This works independently with magnificPopup.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
// if the cookie is undefined, create it

// Cookies.get('visited') returns a string
if (parseInt(Cookies.get('count')) == 3) {
    // open fancybox after 3 secs on 4th visit
    setTimeout(function () {
 $.magnificPopup.open({
     items: {
        src: '#message_popup' //ID OF INLINE ELEMENT
            },
        type:'inline',
  mainClass: 'mfp-zoom-out',
   closeBtnInside: true,
    fixedContentPos: true,
    removalDelay: 500,
        });
    }, 3000);
} 
}); // ready
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a functional solution for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom/popup/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

`enter code here`1. Kalkulator

```
<script>      
$(document).ready(function () {
// if the cookie is undefined, create it
if(typeof Cookies.get('visited') === "undefined"){
    Cookies.set("visited", 1);
}
 else {
    let increase = parseInt(Cookies.get('visited')) + 1;
    Cookies.set('visited', increase, { expires: 1 });
    return false;
}
}); // ready      
</script>  code here
```

`enter code here`2. starter

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function () {

// Cookies.get('visited') returns a string
if (parseInt(Cookies.get('visited')) == 3) {
    // open magnificPopup after 3 secs on 3th visit
    setTimeout(function () {
$.magnificPopup.open({
 items: {
        src: '#message_popup' //ID OF INLINE ELEMENT
            },
        type:'inline',
  mainClass: 'mfp-zoom-out',
   closeBtnInside: true,
    fixedContentPos: true,
    removalDelay: 500,
        });
    }, 3000);
} 
}); // ready  
</script>
```

Comment: Whilst this will work, there are many draw backs to doing this, and this should really be done in state managed by the server - i could clear the cookies and retry unlimited times - wouldnt be hard to see this is how things are working